# When I lose 2FA for Trinity do I still have access using my Seed?

Tags: wallet

I use 2FA and my password to sent transaction via Trinity. When I would lose my smartphone with Google authenticator do I still have the option to get my IOTAs with my Seed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2FA is only use to prevent unauthorized access to the wallet app. As long as you don't lose your seed you will keep access to your funds.